# Will this kind of entanglement of tenses be acceptable?

Tags: tenses

> All dictionaries I consulted say that "nog" is not an English word.
>   （self-made)

Will this kind of entanglement of tenses be acceptable for English? At first, I used past tense, then switched to present tense immediately. But I think it fits well into the reality,my action of consulting a dictionary has become the past, whereas the dictionaries themselves still remain the same, and say the same thing about that word.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your usage of 'says' is wrong. Since you've mentioned 'dictionaries', which is *plural*, you should use 'say'.

> All dictionaries I consulted say that "nog" is not an English word.

*This* doesn't seem wrong to me.

However, I would rather use the perfect tense and say:

> All dictionaries I've consulted say that "nog" is not an English word.

It also sounds better to my ear if I add 'the':

> All the dictionaries I've consulted say that "nog" is not an English word.

Comment: You are right about 'say' and 'says'. But I am wondering why you talk of the 'past perfect'? What you have written here is the simple 'perfect'. By 'past perfect' I always assume that people mean what I would call the 'pluperfect', which in this instance would have been 'All dictionaries I had consulted...' But whether you use the present or the perfect depends on context anyway. It is not a question of preference. Finally I see no value in including 'the'.

Comment: "have consulted" may be better. But "consulted" is permissible, right? Granted that, can "consulted" be used together with "say"?

Comment: @WS2 I'm sorry, that was a genuine mistake. I meant present perfect.  I'll edit it right away. And about the 'the', I've said, it just sounds better to me, and is what I would have said. :)

Comment: @user51369 I've mentioned it above, using 'consulted' doesn't seem wrong to me. You're right, that since the dictionaries still *do* say that, it's better to use the present tense.

Comment: @user51369  It is a pleasure to be of help. But 'consulted' and 'have consulted' carry slight differences in meaning. 'I consulted' nearly always refers to a single instance of consultation. 'I have consulted' or 'I've consulted' suggests you have been looking into dictionaries concerning this over a period of time.

Comment: _All the dictionaries I consulted_ suggests that the process of consultation is over - it might have finished last year, last week, yesterday or this morning, but it is complete. _All the dictionaries I have consulted_ implies that the consultation is continuing: not that I will necessarily look at another one, but that I am thinking of the process as continuing, perhaps with this very question.

Comment: @ColinFine That is true. Perhaps I should have mentioned the differences in the answer.